# How can put my title at top of the ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to put my Title at top of the `ImageView`. However, I can not use `layout_above` to put my title at the top. When I trying this my text is invisible. The title in the last image is exactly the alignment I want. How can I do that?

Code:
[image]

Actual:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please always include images / code directly here. I've edited your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wrap `ImageView` and `TextView` in another `RelativeLayout`.
It's actually easier and more performant to put them both directly in `ConstraintLayout`. Then it's only a question of setting the constraints correctly. Demo code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/above"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title above"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/image"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="400px"
        android:src="@color/purple_200"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/above"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text overlay"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I have more than one ImageView on horizontal. Don't I need Relative Layout for them ? I think once I finished 2 ImageView at horizontal, Than I can copy-paste again under the code.  https://imgur.com/a/SVIbRNe

Comment: You can of course put the ConstraintLayout in another layout e.g. a RelativeLayout. That's what I would suggest. But not the other way around. At least not for your use case. But multiple images were not part of your question anyways right?

Comment: Thank you so much Micheal :) I'm trying to do it right now.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW: instead of copy pasting you could also use a RecyclerView and the code above would be the layout of one item inside the RecyclerView. But if it's only four items like in your link it's probably overkill. Copy paste is then ok I guess :)

Comment: Actually, I am working on multiple images but I did not include at the question.